# SharePoint Designer Workflow to conditionally make a copy of a list item

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, infopath

Good Afternoon,

I am working on an existing SharePoint List with a web enabled infopath form with multiple views, containing questions that are asked at differnt stages of a workflow.

On the very first stage when the list item is created, there is a question with multiple choice (check one). For example, Field Name = Fruits, with values, such as: Apples, Oranges, Cherries.

Later on in the worflow, the user is sent a reminder email, similar to a survey, where questions may look like "What did you think of them apples?

New request from the customer:
In the customers world, every apple eater also eats oranges, and they want also know what the user thinks of oragnes.

So, it sounds like I need to create a conditional worklow that creates a copy of the list item when it is first created, to include all of the initial field values, when Apples is selected, but change the fruit value to oranges in the duplicate. 
Note: The survey reminder is set to create an email reminder when a new item is create in the list.

Using a SharePoint Designer 2013 Workflow, how can I do this?

I noticed that SP Designer will not let me use the "Create item in list (Output to Varialbe:Create)" if the list is the same list. I assume this is by design to not create some sort of infinate loop. I guess MS does not trust that I have a carefully planted condition to only run once, which is what I need your help with.

It feels like a crazy idea, but I am considering making a copy of my list, and using Create item in list (Output to Varialbe:Create) to make a copy of the list item in list 2, to set all value the same, with the exception of fruits, where I would change the value to oranges, and then somehow create a workflow in list #2, to copy the list item back to list #1.

Thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: I am able to do this using a SharePoint 2010 workflow. Even if your site is on 2013, you should still be able to create a 2010 workflow. Have you tried that?

Comment: Thanks.To clarify, using 2010 WF, I see the option for "Create item in List (output to Variable:Create) where I see I can set field values. My concern is that I see a yellow warning that states that "You cannot create an item in the current list, because it will start another instance of the same workflow. Clear the automatically start this workflow when a new item is created check box to fix this problem." If I make it copy to a diff list and then back again, is there risk it would create a loop + crash my server? Any advice how I might set a condition to avoid a loop? Any other thoughts?

Comment: Without trying to test this myself, I would think you could avoid looping by setting conditions. I would suggest having a column in your list that you could use as flag to know if the item needs processed or not. Have the workflow check and set that flag appropriately.